# How to create array from object property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get result like

`arr=['A','B','C','D']`

from the object like below.

```
var obj = { 
  obj1: 'A',
  obj2: [ 'B', 'C', 'D' ] }
```

How to reach out to concatenate to array?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and to get them in one array you can use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
var obj = {
  obj1: 'A',
  obj2: ['B', 'C', 'D']
}

var arr = Object.values(obj).flat()
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Object.values` and spread it into a single array with `Array.prototype.concat` since `Array.prototype.flat` is not supported in older browsers

```js
var obj = {
  obj1: 'A',
  obj2: ['B', 'C', 'D']
}

var vals = [].concat(...Object.values(obj))
console.log(vals)
```

Comment: thank you for answering, sorry for basic questions ,what is the meaning of `...` in front of `Object`? thanks

Comment: That is a spread syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution is to create an array of obj1 and concat the obj2.

```
const arr = [obj.obj1].concat(obj.obj2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` followed by `Object.values()`

```js
var obj = { 
  obj1: 'A',
  obj2: [ 'B', 'C', 'D' ] 
};

const res = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []);

console.log(res);
```